# VS code can't find the headerfiles even when workspace compiles without error

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been having this error where the squiggles in vscode don't go away when I try to include headerfiles for custom messages and services. I am able to compile my workspace, I can see the header file for the service created (with response.h and request.h), I can do rossrv show __________ to see the content of my header files as well. It's just that I can't get rid of the red squiggle because of which I can't use autocomplete.

Does anyone know what can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346258/vs-code-can%27t-find-the-headerfiles-even-when-workspace-compiles-without-error/) by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2020-03-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a great tutorial on how to setup VS-Code properly to work with ROS at https://github.com/RoboGnome/VS_Code_ROS

---

Originally posted by [LazyEngineerToBe](https://answers.ros.org/users/52359/lazyengineertobe/) with karma: 91 on 2020-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-03-11**:
This looks great, Thanks.

**Comment by [LazyEngineerToBe](https://answers.ros.org/users/52359/lazyengineertobe/) on 2020-03-11**:
don't forget to upvote an answer and close your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to add the proper include path for the msgs the you should handle those

The config file is:
c_cpp_properties.json
See here

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-03-09**:
Okay, I'll have a look, Thanks!

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-03-09**:
you may look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros looks interresting

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-03-10**:
I have that extension already, still doesn't get the header files.
Btw, do you know if adding these lines to my CMakelist would be helpful or not?

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES generate_waypoint
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs tf visualization_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

I usually just have all of them commented out, resulting in `catkin_package()`

And also this:

```
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

By default the include is commented out though, resulting in:

```
include_directories(
  # include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```